# Firefox cache in C#

Tags: asp.net

In my ASP site there's a function for upload images and display upload image in data grid view  but my problem is when we upload image and replace later one it's doesn't appear change in data grid without reload page.but this problem doesn't occured  in google chrome .

Comment: Are you rebinding the datagrid and calling its DataBind at the point which you are uploading the image to the server? Check to see where you are calling the DataGrid's .DataSource = ? and .DataBind();

Comment: yeah, i used .DataBind() for rebind data for the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image will likely be getting cached on the browser. try either

1. forcing it to have a different url every time its updated
2. adding a last modified header to your response to the image request, that is the the write time of the file.

Comment: Thanks all,Problem is caching image and i found the solution that each time when get image url from database i added random number for end with the "?" mark                                 Eval("ImgThumb") + "?" +  new Random().Next().ToString()       it's worked

Comment: your solution isnt particularly efficient, that will mean a new request for every image every time with no caching. If bandwidth usage isn't a problem it is fine however.